# MySQL Order by on calculated column slow

Tags: mysql, sorting, select

I'm calculating scores based on input parameters and sorting them to get a list of the top 10 athletes. Querying the scores is fast(about < 100ms). But When I start sorting them the query takes > 1.5 seconds(far to slow for my needs).

So I got a table athlete

```
athlete
idAthlete | name
1         | foo
2         | bar
```

and a table result

```
result
idResult | idAthlete | place | type
1        | 1         | 2     | World championship
2        | 3         | 1     | European championship
```

In my database I have ~40000 entries for the table result

And a query

```
SELECT athlete.idAthlete,
        SUM(IF((FIND_IN_SET(result.type, @compTypes)), GETSCORE(result.place), 0)) AS score
            
    FROM
       athlete
       LEFT JOIN result ON result.idPerson = athlete.idAthlete
    GROUP BY athlete.idAthlete
    ORDER BY score desc
    LIMIT 10;
```

@compTypes is a string in the form of "World championship,European championship,..."

I tried storing the result without an order by clause in a temporary table and then sorting that. This approach worked but wasn't any faster.

I would really appreciate any ideas. I'm sitting at this problem for a while now and probably forgot about something obvious. Thank you :)

Comment: You seem to be loking for the haystack in the needle. Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what's the GETSCORE() function  ... ???

Comment: Sorting on a calculated field is always slow, since mysql cannot use indexes to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

How many athletes exist? This is the number of rows that must get sorted. The lower this number, the faster the sort. So, if you can limit the potential top 10 somehow, sorting may become much faster.

This is how I'd write your query. The difference is that I only join results the types of which we want to consider. (This doesn't speed up sorting, however.)

```
select a.idathlete, coalesce(sum(getscore(r.place)), 0) as score
from athlete a
left join result r on r.idathlete = a.idathlete and find_in_set(r.type, @comptypes)
group by a.idathlete
order by score desc
limit 10;
```

If it's okay to only show athletes that have results, remove the `athletes` table from the query:

```
select idperson, sum(getscore(place)) as score
from result 
where find_in_set(type, @comptypes)
group by idperson
order by score desc
limit 10;
```

If it's further okay to limit this to athletes that have a score of at least *n*, add a `HAVING` clause. Here is an example for *n* = 100.

```
group by idperson
having score >= 100
order by score desc
limit 10;
```

The higher that value *n*, the less rows to sort.

For efficient data access I'd provide these indexes:

```
create index idx1 on athlete (idathlete);
create index idx2 on result (idperson, type, place);
create index idx3 on result (type, idperson, place);
```

With `idathlete` being obviously the primary key for the table `athlete`, you should have the index idx1 already.

Depending on the query and the data, either idx2 or idx3 or none of the two will be used. Check this with `EXPLAIN` and drop the unused one(s).